# Web service Parser Error

Tags: .net

After I have sent the proejct to the server.. I am getting this error... (Webservice)

I don't understand

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebService1.Service1'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="c#" Codebehind="Service1.asmx.cs" Class="WebService1.Service1" %>

Comment: Is this the start of a brand new project that you're just trying to host to get started?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help. Maybe post the Service class, the Interface class, web.config and how you're pushing it to your web server? (Are you using the publish utility, compiling and copying, installer, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Configuration Manager (under the Build menu) and be sure your service project has the "Build" checkbox checked.

Answer (score -1):

try to view markup. then make sure the namespace in code view same with WebService1 in the tag.